# jQuery ajax does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 in a web app running on WebLogic 10.3.2. I do ajax GETs to the server. This all works fine in FF and Chrome, but nothing happens for the ajax events in IE 8. It's as if the doc ready didn't set them up at all.

Here's some of the js:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/messaging.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.dynatree.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.cluetip.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dynatree.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cluetip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {                                              
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
         },
         crossDomain: true
    });
...
$('#findSites').click(function() {                                // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
searchVal = document.getElementById("searchFor").value;
searchTyp = document.getElementById("searchType").value;
$.get('SiteSearchServlet', {searchFor: searchVal, searchType: searchTyp}, function(responseJson) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response JSON...
...
```

I've tried leaving off the charset, using only cache=false in ajaxsetup - didn't help. The $.get ajax call doesn't execute when the findSites button is clicked.

Can anyone tell me the secret to getting jQuery ajax GETs to work on IE?

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` or `alert()` at the point where the `$.get()` is does _that_ execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using $.ajax instead of $.get, that way you can add an error callback and see why the ajax call is failing.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
(see the Finally... section at the end)

Comment: Thanks - I added ".error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error: " + errorThrown); })" to my $.get instead (same thing really) and got a "no transport" error.  Google search says that's related to cross-domain issues.  I then added this line to force IE to allow this: "jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting". This got the ajax call to work! Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: glad it helped. make sure you set jQuery.support.cors back to false after your ajax call to prevent unwanted or unintended XSS.